# matching rows in all the columns in the QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

If the current search button is pressed, the corresponding row is displayed only if it matches the values ​​in the second column.

I want to search on all the columns and output all matching rows.

I tried using rowCount() and ColumnCount() in addition to the item() function, but I did not get the desired result.

```py
    self.SearchEdit = QLineEdit()
    self.SearchEdit.setPlaceholderText("KeyWord")
    self.SearchButton = QPushButton("search")
    self.SearchButton.clicked.connect(self.OnSearch)

def OnSearch(self):
    if self.SearchEdit.text() == "":
        for i in range(0, tableWidget.rowCount()):
            tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, False)
        return
    for i in range(0, tableWidget.rowCount()):
        item = tableWidget.item(i,1)
        if (item is not None and item.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole) == (self.SearchEdit.text())):
            tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, False)
        else:
            tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, True)
```

Only one specific column is being searched. I want to be able to do a search for all the columns.

Comment: Do you want that if an item in the row matches the search then the row is visible?

Comment: Yes. There are currently 7 columns. However, currently only certain columns can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to hide the rows that none of your items match the search then a strategy is to use a flag that indicates if the search found the match:

```py
def OnSearch(self):
    word = self.SearchEdit.text()
    if word:
        for i in range(tableWidget.rowCount()):
            match = False
            for j in range(tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = tableWidget.item(i, j)
                if item is not None and item.text() == word:
                    match = True
                    break
            tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, not match)
    else:
        for i in range(tableWidget.rowCount()):
            tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, False)
```

Comment: Wow ~ Thank you very much. I've been wondering for a few hours, I've posted a question and it's solved. I learned that using flags makes it easy to fix.

Comment: @ParkSeokEun This logic is generic, so I recommend you review some algorithm course

Comment: Let's review the algorithmic lectures and documentation. Thank you.